# Is it possible to pass a variable into a piped powershell script?

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I'm basing a small project off of the below one-liner, but I'm struggling to pass parameters into it on the same line.

```
irm get.scoop.sh | iex
```

This script can take additional parameters, such as `-ScoopDir`.

How does one pass `-ScoopDir C:\foo\bar` into the one-liner?

Comment: `& ([scriptblock]::Create((irm get.scoop.sh))) -ScoopDir C:\foo\bar`

Comment: Glorious.  Want to post it as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be done with `Invoke-Expression`, however you can do it by converting the expression into a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.3) first then you can pass arguments as if it was a function.

Do note:

[image: iex]

This still applies for the `[scriptblock]::Create(...)` approach.

```bash
& ([scriptblock]::Create((irm get.scoop.sh))) -ScoopDir C:\foo\bar
```

Comment: Thanks! Does exactly as described[!](https://github.com/qzind/qz.sh/blob/main/README.md#powershell)